# How to generate React elements using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using the hackernews api I am trying to use my response object to get the property "data" to render the individual story titles to the browser. Originally, the data is in an array of id's representing individual stories. I make a second request passing in the id's to get all the stories. As of now, all the titles rapidly appear in the browser on one line.

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
     storyIds: null,
     title: null
    }
   } // constructor end

  componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('https://hacker-        news.firebaseio.com/v0/beststories.json?print=pretty')
// use arrow to access state

  .then((res) => { 

// res.data is array of story ids

   this.setState({storyIds: res.data})
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(this.state.storyIds)
      this.state.storyIds.map ((id) => {  
         axios.get(`https://hackernews.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}/title.json?print=pretty`)
        .then((res) =>{ 
          this.setState( {title: res.data})

          console.log(res.data)
        })
      })
  })

 } // didMount end

  render() {
   return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to Hackernews Top Stories</h2>
        </div>
          <p>{this.state.title}</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How do I loop over my response.data with map and generate the titles on individual lines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function to .map over the titles and return a jsx element with the title. You should also use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve all of your ajax calls.

```
function storyTitles(titles) {
   return titles.map(title => (
     <p>{title}</p>
   ))
 }

 class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super()
     this.state = {
      storyIds: [],
      titles: []
     }
    } // constructor end

   componentDidMount () {
     axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/beststories.json?print=pretty')
       .then((res) => { 
         this.setState({storyIds: res.data})
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(this.state.storyIds)
          Promise.all(this.state.storyIds.map((id) => {
            axios.get(`https://hackernews.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}/title.json?print=pretty`)
            .then((res) => { 
              return Promise.resolve(res.data);
            })
          )
            .then(responses => {
              this.setState({titles: [...responses]})
            })
          })
        })

  } // didMount end



   render() {
    return (
       <div className="App">
         <div className="App-header">
           <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
           <h2>Welcome to Hackernews Top Stories</h2>
         </div>
         {storyTitles(this.state.titles)}   
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading about Promise objects, I'm not too familiar with them. In the Promise.all section, the value to be resolved extends all the way to just above  " .then(responses =>  ..."?

Comment: They are essential to asynchronous JS. When you call 'axios.get()' you are returning a promise. Your '.then()'  method is called when that promise is resolved. The 'Promise.resolve()' is also a resolved promise just like your axios call except that I've explicitly returned it and passed it the actual data payload.

Comment: Promise.all is a promise that resolves when all elements of an array which passed to it are resolved. It then returns a resolved promise with the result array. In this case it is an array of all the response.datas that were resolved..... That's alot of use of the word 'resolve' lol I hope it makes sense.

Comment: When you call `this.state.stroyIds.map()` you are returning an array of values that is the result of your `(id) => {}` function being called on each element of the array. In this case we are returning `Promise.resolve(res.data)` for each element.

Comment: `Promise.all()` waits for each array element to be resolved.

Comment: sure give me a sec

Comment: want to jump on a discord and I can help you out real quick? https://discord.gg/j7ZaY

Comment: i'm going there now